# will sshfs use my .ssh/config?

Tags: sshfs

I have some options in my ~/.ssh/config:

Host * Ciphers arcfour,blowfish-cbc

These options are intended to speed up transfers.
Will sshfs use these options when I do a mount?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, sshfs simply calls plain old ssh which is also why you can use your per-host configuration from .ssh/config. Using -F you can specify a different ssh_config if that's what you need.